# What is the best way to represent a large number of dots in SVG?

Tags: svg, vector-graphics

I am working on [a program](https://github.com/jwezorek/crosshatching) that generates crosshatched images and now stippled images as SVG from raster input. With stippling however, representing each dot as a filled circle has made it such that medium to large sized raster images can result in SVG files that are so large Illustrator and InkScape fail to open them.

I am however currently making no effort to optimize the representation of stippling in the SVG. Is there perhaps an SVG element that is specially for representing a collection of points? Or can a polyline be styled such that it is rendered as just its vertices represented as circles?

Comment: Sounds like canvas would be a more appropriate technology for you.

Comment: Like an HTML5 canvas? That's just raster. If I want raster output I can already write to a .png. I am using SVG as a vector file format such that artwork generated by my program can be imported into an application like Illustrator or InkScape for further vector manipulation. Another option would be to export to PDF but wanted to try more optimized SVG first because PDF export would be difficult to implement,

Comment: [This article](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/the-power-of-css-blend-modes/), among other effects, describes making halftone images via a filter function. But that is only a live modification of a raster image, so probably not what you want.